# Change Magento2 default DB credantials - config file location

Tags: magento2, configuration

I have installed Magento2 project

but in `app/etc`, there is no `env.php` 
file and in console when I run `./magento:install` 
I receive exception that DB credential is bad for `root@localhost` which is good.

I need info how to change default magento2 setup.

Comment: seems like you made some mistake when entering the DB credentials. The exception is pretty clear about it.

Comment: So is there solution to change credentials manually? I need config file location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution.

Simple run this command from terminal

```
/var/www/magento/magento2/bin$ ./magento setup:install --db-user=root --db-password=123456
```